# kubernetes does not deploy HorizontalPodAutoscaler when applied within range

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, horizontalpodautoscaler

When I am applying helm deployment yaml file in below format (with range) deployment works fine but it applies HorizontalPodAutoscaler only for one of the deployment.

```
{{- range .Values.services }}
{{ if .enabled }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
{{- range .Values.services }}
Metadata:
.
.
.
spec:
.
.
.
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: mlservice-{{.name}}-v{{.version}}
  namespace: {{$.Values.namespace }}
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  name: mlservice-{{.name}}-v{{.version}}
minReplicas: {{ $.Values.minReplicas }}
maxReplicas: {{ $.Values.maxReplicas }}
targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: {{ $.Values.targetCPUUtilizationPercentage }}
{{ end }}
{{- end }}
```

github action logs I see like :

client.go:239: [debug] Created a new HorizontalPodAutoscaler called "**service-v1**" in namespace

but I don't see anything like
Created a new HorizontalPodAutoscaler called "**service-v2**"

No clue why , I am using aws EKS and complete workload works fine. except doing "kubectl get hpa" returns only one service. Before I had only one service and auto scaling and all workload used to work fine.

Comment: try `kubectl get hpa --all-namespaces` to see if it's gone onto another namespace instead.

Comment: @BlenderFox Already checked , not there.

Comment: Might be worth trying `helm template {chart-location} -n {name-of-release} --namespace {namespace-of-release} -f {path-to-values-yaml} 2>&1 >helm.log`  and see what actually generates into the helm.log file. If the hpa template renders as empty, that's why you're not seeing anything when deploying, and you'll need to check your values

Comment: @BlenderFox Thank you for the suggestion Fixed the issue see my answer
I did checked helm logs and all generated yamls. It did generated all yamls properly, but realized that 2nd HPA overwrote the 1st HPA and realized it because of not having '---' at end of yaml.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this HPA issue :
need to add '---' at end of HorizontalPodAutoscaler section in deployment.yaml this is required because it is inside loop and k8s needs to understand that iteration is over.